# React Native Firebase Date Comparison

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the date the user joined which is present in the firebase document as such:

[image: firebase joined field]

I've got this function to query the logged in user and get the data:

```
import { auth, firestore } from '../../firebase/fire';

const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
const user = auth.currentUser;

const GetUserData = async() =>{
    const response = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
    const observer = response.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
        if( docSnapshot.exists ) {
            setUserData(docSnapshot.data());
          }
    }, err => {
      console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
    });
    const unsub = firestore.collection('users').onSnapshot(() => {
        setUserData({});
    });
    unsub();        
}
useEffect(() => {
    GetUserData();
}, [])
```

This gives me access to set something like `const joined = userData.joined;`

console logging this gives me

```
  "nanoseconds": 0,
  "seconds": 1489615200,
}
```

Now this can be converted to a normal date via `.toDate()` but doesn't seem to work.

**What I tried**
Using toDate() as such:

```
const joined = userData.joined.toDate();
console.log(joined);
```

**Error I'm getting**

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'joined.toDate')`

My purpose is to get that date find the amount of months difference between now and then and display that.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" Why not? Can you edit your question to show what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Added in what I tried + error I'm receiving.

Comment: It seems that `userData.joined` does not have a value when you call `toDate()` on it. Where (or more accurately: when) are you running that code? Can you edit your question to show a single fragment of code that (when we run it) reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the date to pull through buy using:

```
const joined = userData.joined;
const date = joined.toDate().toDateString();
console.log(date);
```

Thu Mar 16 2017

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that console logging the `joined` date gives you the output in seconds and nanoseconds. So you are getting the data from Firestore.

This `joined` timestamp can be converted to date using the `toDate()` function. It worked for me perfectly. As you are getting the error, in your case there might be no value in `userData.joined` when you are calling the `toDate()` function on it. For that, as mentioned in the comment section by ***Frank van Puffelen***, it will be easy to reproduce if you can edit the question and include where and when you are running that code in a more detailed manner.

Next you have mentioned that you want to get the difference in months between now and the `joined` date.

For that there are a number of ways. I hope the following will be an easy and short method -

Run the following command to install the `date-fns` library.

`npm install -s date-fns`

Then follow the code sample -

```
const differenceInMonths = require('date-fns/differenceInMonths');
const today = new Date();
const joined = userData.joined.toDate();
const monthDiff= differenceInMonths(today,joined);
console.log(monthDiff);
```